# Lightning Components: Unable to handle an event

Tags: event, lightning

I have a component which consists of another child component which is added dynamically:

```
<aura:component>
    <ltng:require styles="/resource/SLDS0122/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system-ltng.css" />
     <aura:attribute name="attachments" type="Aura.Component[]" description="Array of Components for adding attachement components"/>
                <aura:handler name="removeAttachment" event="c:removeAttachment" action="{!c.removeAttachment}"/>
    <div class="slds-attachments">
       <!--File attachment components are added here -->
           {!v.attachments}
     </div>
    </aura:component>
```

And child component which has a registered event as follows:childComponent

```
<aura:component>
    <!-- Handler -->
    <aura:Handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
    <aura:registerEvent name="removeAttachment" type="c:removeAttachment"/>
<button class="slds-button slds-button--icon-bare" onclick="{!c.fireRemoveAttachmentEvt}"/>
</aura:component>
```

Controller:

```
{
    fireRemoveAttachmentEvt : function(cmp,evt,hlpr){
        console.log("Inside fireRemoveAttachmentEvt");
        var removeAttachEvt = cmp.getEvent("removeAttachment");
        console.log(removeAttachEvt.getName());
        removeAttachEvt.fire(); 
    },
}
```

Now i am able to handle the event if put a handler in the same component, but if i try to handle the event in an another component, the method referenced in the action attribute of handler is not executed.

Any help on this greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: For events of type components there are accessible only via top parent component .Make your event of type application

Comment: Check here for more info https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/events_component.htm

Comment: Yup. Made the event type application. Still doesn't work

Comment: @kathikeya Please share your entire code so that I can have better look

Comment: CaseFeedPublisher: [link](http://pastebin.com/m64Xq4Tz)

Comment: [caseFeedPublisherController](http://pastebin.com/MRN7KwHF) [caseFeedAttachment](http://pastebin.com/C9F9tVsZ)  [caseFeedAttachmentController](http://pastebin.com/CX3ej7cC)

Comment: [Event](http://pastebin.com/X3mfHnMV)

Comment: @Kathikeya This sounds like a bug to me .Raise a case with SFDC support .Something like this one http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/106392/event-fired-by-a-dynamically-created-component-does-not-get-caught

Comment: Okay. Thank you for responding to my question. I will raise a case with salesforce

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way i was able to make this work was referencing the event handling method while creating the components. Check the below code for example.

```
$A.createComponent(
                "c.caseFeedCommentAttachment",
                {
                    "isFileValid" : isFileValid,
                    "filename":inputFileList[i].name,
                    "filePath":fileURL,
                    "filetype":inputFileList[i].type,
                    "fileSize":fileSize,
                    "aura:id":inputFileList[i].name+uploadCounter.toString(),
                    "removeAttachment" : component.getReference("c.handleRemoveAttachmentEvt")
                },
```

Note: Also i have removed the event handler on the Parent component, just to check if the method is called. It still works which is confusing.

Comment: That's totally odd. Any idea why this works? Is that documented somewhere?

Comment: I think this happened due to a bug where the registerEvent component failed to create a reference to the event in the dynamically created component context. So when i try to get the event and fire it which calls the event handler in another component controller, it failed because there is no such event associated with that name. But when i pass the handler as a reference directly, it works.

Answer (score 3):

I think that is the same issues as mentioned here: [Event fired by a dynamically created component does not get caught](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/106392/event-fired-by-a-dynamically-created-component-does-not-get-caught) - have an eye at the comments from Doug Chasman.

As I understood there is a bug in the framework which prevents event bubbling for dynamically created components. Workaround will be the usage of application event (also mentioned in the post).

Comment: Any word on when the bug will be fixed, is there a link to a known issue, it still appears to be broken