# Lightning event fired but not catched?

Tags: lightning, event

i have a problem to catch a fired event, everything is in place (i think) but the component that should catch the event simply does not, here is my code:

The function that fire the event ( **ContractList**):

```
updateTable: function(component, event, helper) {

    var cmpTarget = component.find('Confirmation');
    $A.util.removeClass(cmpTarget, 'slds-show');
    $A.util.addClass(cmpTarget, 'slds-hide');
    var ItemTobeUpdated = component.get("v.ItemToBeUpdated");
    var updateEvent = component.getEvent("UpdateTableItem");
    updateEvent.setParams({ "contract": ItemTobeUpdated });
    updateEvent.fire();
```

console.log('Event fired');
    },

The component markup (**ontractList**):

```
    <aura:attribute name="contracts" type="Contract[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" />
    <aura:attribute name="ItemToBeUpdated" type="Contract" />
    <aura:registerEvent name="UpdateTableItem" type="c:ContractItemUpdate"/>
    <aura:handler name="SendConfirmationBox" event="c:SendConfirmationBoxEvent"
   action="{!c.DispalyNotification}"/>
```

the component function that should catch the event (**Contracts**):

```
  handleUpdateContract: function(component, event, helper) {
        console.log('Je suis dans handleUpdateContract');
        var updatedContract = event.getParam("contract");
        console.log(updatedContract);
        helper.updateContract(component, updatedContract);
    }
```

the markup (**Contracts**)

```
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" />
    <aura:attribute name="contracts" type="Contract[]"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.doInit}" value="{!this}"/>
   <aura:handler name="UpdateTableItem" event="c:ContractItemUpdate"
   action="{!c.handleUpdateContract}"/>
   <aura:registerEvent name="NotifierUtilisateurMessageEvent" type="c:NotifierUtilisateurMessage"/>
```

Just to be clear, the console.log('Event fired') is printed out when the event is fired, so the problem would be in the catcher component.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code. Just a wild guess, Do you think is there any chance that event is fired before the receiving component is ready?

Comment: No, the receiving component get executed first when the page loaded, i do not think that this is the reason @javanoob. Unless there is something missing, i would go for a salesforce bug.

Comment: We have similar code running on Spring 17, Winter 17 and it is working fine. I don't think Salesforce bug.

Comment: Are you trying this on Spring 17?

Comment: No i am on winter

Comment: i found some related issues http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/113086/lightning-components-unable-to-handle-an-event?rq=1

Comment: Try removing the `name` attribute on the `<aura:handler>` tag and see if it works..I don't think `name` attribute is required.

Comment: Is contract list used inside of contract. The component level event bubbles up.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need the name attribute.  That way you can have the same event component be handled in different ways.  I do know that I have it on all my components.

Comment: @manjit_singh, yes of course , ContractList component is a child of contracts

Comment: @MerabtiIbrahim Did you figure this out? I am curious to know the reason..