# Component event handler not invoked

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-events

I have a hierarchy of components as shown below:

```
        c:DataGridContainer
                 |__ c:DataGrid
                          |__ c:DataTable
```

I have defined a component event(DGGetGridDataEvent) as shown below:

```
<aura:event type="COMPONENT" description="Indicates request to change the page of the data table." access="public">

<aura:attribute name="pageNumber" type="Integer" />
<aura:attribute name="pageSize" type="Integer"/>
<aura:attribute name="columnLabel" type="String" />
<aura:attribute name="columnName" type="String" />
<aura:attribute name="sortDirection" type="String" />
```

The c:DGTable component registers the event as shown below:

```
<aura:registerEvent name="getGridDataEvent" type="c:DGGetGridDataEvent"/>
```

and fires the event as shown below:

```
var getGridDataEvent = component.getEvent("getGridDataEvent");

    getGridDataEvent.setParams({
        'pageNumber' : pageNumber,
        'pageSize' : pageSize,
        'columnName':'',
        'sortDirection':'',
        'actionType': 'Pagination'
    });
    getGridDataEvent.fire();
```

The c:DataGridContainer has a handler defined as shown below:

```
<aura:handler name="dgGetGridDataEvent" event="c:DGGetGridDataEvent" action="{!c.handleDataFetchEvent}" phase="capture"/>
```

and the handler definition is as shown below:

```
handleDataFetchEvent : function(component, event, helper){}
```

However, when the event is fired the handler is not invoked. What's wrong with the code i have written?

Comment: Any `stopPropagation()` calls stopping the event?

Comment: @KeithC Well, i haven't done any such thing myself explicitly in my code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are missing (And it is not shown in the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/events_demo.htm)) but is shown in the link below. It may be a bug or, a doc error...

[Handling Custom Events in the Lightning Component Framework](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/03/lightning-component-framework-custom-events.html)

```
<c:DGTable getGridDataEvent="{!c:DGGetGridDataEvent}"/>
```

Related Question(s):

[Lightning Components: Unable to handle an event](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/113086/lightning-components-unable-to-handle-an-event)

[Event fired by a dynamically created component does not get caught](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/106392/event-fired-by-a-dynamically-created-component-does-not-get-caught)

Is that you have to specify the event when creating the component

Comment: You won't believe me if i say there's another event which i created first(In fact that's the first event i created in my org) which works perfectly fine(as mentioned in the docs) for the same flow. When i tried creating new events i started facing this problem. So, i was curious to know what was actually happening!

Comment: @Anee well in one of the links Doug says it has to be done this way and since he is on the Lightning team I tend to think it is worth a shot to see if it resolves your issue.