# Dynamically created aura component doesn't handle event

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have parent component where I create child components dynamically with $A.createCmponent:

```
$A.createComponent(
                'c:' + setting.Child_Component__c,
                attributes,
                function(newComponent, status, errorMessage) {
                    if (status === "SUCCESS") {
                        component.set('v.childComponent', newComponent);

                        let appEvent = $A.get("e.c:appEvent");
                        appEvent.setParams({ "myParam" : myValue });
                        appEvent.fire();
                    
                    } else {
                        console.log('Error: ' + errorMessage);
                    }
                }
            );
```

And I'm firing an event when status is success. I'm trying to handle this event in dynamically created component but it doesn't work. What I'm doing wrong? Event is Application. And handled by another not dynamically created components

Comment: Please check if any of the solutions posted over this [thread](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/106392/event-fired-by-a-dynamically-created-component-does-not-get-caught) helps.

Comment: @ShivankurNaikwade I saw this, my situation is opposite to that